# Ipython: Cannot import name download / no such option

Tags: python, ipython

I installed the complete pattern package:

- pip install pattern

When I want to use `download`, I get the following message:

```
ImportError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-83512f2723dc> in <module>()
      6 
      7 from pattern.web import PDF
----> 8 from pattern.web import download, plaintext
      9 from textblob_de import TextBlobDE as TextBlob
     10 

ImportError: cannot import name download
```

I allready got help, somebody told me to "--upgrade pattern".

But when I do this:

- pip --upgrade pattern

the cmd says:

pip <"command"> [options]

no such option: --upgrade

So how can I upgrade pattern?

Answer (score 0):

In the pip [Docs/Examples](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples), to upgrade a package, you need to use the install command , like so

```
$ pip install --upgrade SomePackage
```